# jquery-ajax working differently in mozilla and chrome

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jquery

I have a rather strange issue. I am using google maps api to find lat/long using zipcode and the script is as follows :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
      url:"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code:695564&sensor=false",
      type: "POST",
      success:function(res){
         console.log(res.results[0].geometry.location.lat);
         console.log(res.results[0].geometry.location.lng);
      }
    });

});
```

The above code works perfectly in google chrome, but it gives an error in mozilla :

```
TypeError: data.results is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

console.log(data.results[0]);
```

When i debug, i get the console for `console.log(data)`, but nothing beyond that.

Jsbin link :  http://jsbin.com/ilipaNa/1/edit

Firefox version : 18.0.2

Cheers

Comment: Im getting TypeError: res.results is undefined in jsbin and same in my app..:(

Comment: inspect request itself in network tab...also suggest setting `dataType:'json'`

Comment: Awesome.. when i added dataType it worked in FF too..

Comment: @VickyGonsalves, thats the error from my application. I cut out just the jquery-ajax part and made a jsbin to put it here..

Comment: just noticed results I'm getting are in India...I live in USA. From memory of geocode api, if no mtch don't get results array  `"Kerala 695564, India"`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40932/discussion-between-roy-m-j-and-charlietfl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the following and error was resolved :

```
dataType:'json'
```

Although the answer is obtained via comment, im posting here to close out the question.

Complete solution :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url:"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code:695564&sensor=false",
      dataType:'json',
      type: "POST",
      success:function(res){
         console.log(res.results[0].geometry.location.lat);
         console.log(res.results[0].geometry.location.lng);
      }
    });
});
```